# How to convert a api object to json file , if that object is a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

i have this api https://run.mocky.io/v3/8bcd666d-b83c-43dd-b166-a86854dfa811
it's not an object , its a string

```
obj = "{
  club: {
    title: 'CLUB-Rs 300',
    rows: '2',
    columns: 15,
    price: 300,
    name: 'club',
  },
  executive: {
    title: 'Executive-Rs 200',
    rows: '8',
    columns: 15,
    price: 200,
    name: 'executive',
  },
}"
```

i want to convert this in to json file object

Comment: Fix the API so it returns valid JSON instead of almost-JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

the format of the json is wrong, you need to add doble quotes on the name of the properties object, remove comas on the lasts properties of each object.

it will look something like this

```
{
  "club": {
    "title": "CLUB-Rs 300",
    "rows": "2",
    "columns": 15,
    "price": 300,
    "name": "club"
  },
  "executive": {
    "title": "Executive-Rs 200",
    "rows":"8",
    "columns": 15,
    "price": 200,
    "name": "executive"
  }
}
```